# How to give link to edit in user profile page and node page?

Tags: users, navigation

I have removed all tabs of user's page and node page with the help of [Tab Tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module, but i want to keep only one tab enabled i.e "Edit".

how to enabled only tab(Edit) or a link to edit profile on the user's page and edit link on node page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/config/system/tabtamer and enable tabs as you want.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The module you're using ([Tab Tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer)) lets you individually disable and enable each tab.  Navigate to *admin » config » system » tabtamer* to do it.  Note that for *any* tab to show, you need to always keep the *View* tab enabled.

See illustration below for enabling the *Edit* tab and disabling the *Revisions* tab.

[image]

If you don't want the *View* tab to show, but still want to provide users with permissions to update (i.e. edit) with a link which redirect to the edit page for the node, put the follwoing code snipped in your `node.tpl.php` in the place in the template where you want the link to appear.

```
if (node_access('update', $node)) {
  // Create link to the the edit page for the current node.
  echo l(t('Edit this node'), 'node/' . $node->nid . '/edit');
}
```